# TCP/IP Connections with Postgres on Virtual Server

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I'm trying to connect my local gui for postgres to a virtual server that I have running postgres.

I can

```
su postgres_user
```

Then

```
pgsql
```

Here pgsql loads.

When I go to my pg_hba.conf I have

```
host    all    all    x.x.x.x/24    trust
```

In postgresql.conf

```
listen_addresses = 'localhost,x.x.x.x'
```

I have ubuntu 16 and postgres 9.5

I have the issue when I try to connect I get the error:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused...Is the server running on host "hostip" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using linode, you must either whitelist your ip or use putty (in windows) to tunnel postgres to connect to it.

putty tunneling is easier, however more annoying to deal with on a day to day basis

Follow the tutorial here.
[here](https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/postgresql/securely-manage-remote-postgresql-servers-with-pgadmin-on-windows)

Note, it's the same for PGAdmin as it is for any gui in windows.